# Why (function(){return this}).bind(1).bind(2)() returns 1?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Why this returns `1` instead of expected `2`?

```
(function() { 
    return this
})
 .bind(1)
 .bind(2)()
```

Looked up Mozilla's `bind` reference, but it did not help to understand it.

Comment: why would you expect it to be 2?

Comment: @Thomas because first `bind` returns a function, and I expect to bind any value to it as I can do to any other function.

Comment: What is purpose of passing `1` to first `.bind()` if expected result is `2`?